# Import Excel Worksheet with images and images into Pervasive SQL Table

Tags: sql, excel, import, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I'm currently using Pervasive SQL Control Center Version 9.50 and am currently trying to import an excel worksheet that has several columns including an image column into a new table on a database. I've been trying several method but none of them have worked and almost everything that pops up in google is useless or for another type of SQL manager.

Also I would like to know how to insert images into a pervasive SQL table. I've been trying a bulk method but had not any luck with it.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried and what, if any, errors are you getting?  If you're not getting errors, what's not working the way you expect it?
What does your table structure look like?  Do you have a LongVarBinary field defined?

Comment: Hello, in terms of adding images to the table I defined a LongVarBinary Field called picture and tried using this statement to add a picture into it:     Insert Into Products(ID, Image)
   Select '1', BulkColumn 
   from Openrowset (Bulk 'D:\thepathofimage.jpg', Single_Blob) as Image

Comment: I've figured how to import and excel spreadsheet using bdu but it still can't import the images in every row.

Comment: Is it giving an error? Is it just not importing an image?  What's the behavior?

Comment: It just imports everything else but not the images. Is there any way i can save all the images of the excel in a folder and add all of them to the table with an UPDATE?